# using Google APIs account to handle multiple users in my app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I have a web app in which I need to use the google translation and language detection API. Following the docs I can consume the API using my service account. However, I have different clients (users) who use my service and each one should be billed separately, so I need a way to calculate the pricing for each user separately.

I read on other SO questions that making a service account per client is a bad idea. Also, I need a way to allow each user to enable/disable the translation feature programatically  (my web app is a service on the cloud, so for example if the solution was to create a service acc/user, then I need a programmatic way to do that). Any ideas about the best available way to handle this?